# Builder Design Pattern To Store User Information

Tags: php, design-patterns

I am new to building with design patterns. I have been working on implementing the builder design pattern in PHP. I just want to make sure I am doing it correctly. I have been following along with this tutorial on jakowicz:
 https://www.jakowicz.com/builder-pattern-in-php/

I have made a few minor changes to the way I'm implementing the pattern but nothing too major. I just hope I am doing it correctly.

User.php

```
class User
{
    public $user;
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;
    public $company;
    public $address;
    public $city;
    public $state;
    public $zip;

}
```

UserBuilderInterface.php

```
interface UserBuilderInterface
{
    public function setFirstName($firstName);
    public function setLastName($lastName);
    public function setCompany($company);
    public function setAddress($address);
    public function setCity($city);
    public function setState($state);
    public function setZip($zip);

    public function storeUser();
    public function getUser();
}
```

UserBuilder.php

```
class UserBuilder extends User implements UserBuilderInterface {

    public function __construct(){
        $this->user = new User();
    }

    public function setFirstName($firstName){
        $this->user->firstName = $firstName;
    }

    public function setLastName($lastName){
        $this->user->lastName = $lastName;
    }

    public function setCompany($company){
        $this->user->company = $company;
    }

    public function setAddress($address){
        $this->user->address = $address;
    }

    public function setCity($city){
        $this->user->city = $city;
    }

    public function setState($state){
        $this->user->state = $state;
    }

    public function setZip($zip){
        $this->user->zip = $zip;
    }

    public function getUser(){
        return $this->user;
    }



}
```

UserDirector.php

```
class UserDirector{

    public static function create(UserBuilderInterface $set, $first, $last, $company, $address, $city, $state, $zip){
        $set->setFirstName($first);
        $set->setLastName($last);
        $set->setCompany($company);
        $set->setAddress($address);
        $set->setCity($city);
        $set->setState($state);
        $set->setZip($zip);
        return $set->getUser();
    }
}
```

index.php

```
$user = UserDirector::create(new UserBuilder,'John', 'Doe', 'Foo', '1444 Foo Bar Ave', 'Fo', 'FO', '11111');

echo 'First Name:' . $user->firstName;
echo 'Last Name:' . $user->lastName;
```

BTW everything runs as expected. Just want to know if Im doing it right? Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

edit: My code will be used to store User information into a database. It is not for production use it is just to learn how to implement a design pattern

Comment: Please tell us what your builder is for and put this also in the title. It should describe the purpose of your code, not your concerns about it.

Comment: What's the empty `storeUser()` method doing there? Either fill it in or remove it from the question.

Comment: @t3chb0t I edited the code to tell you what it was doing. It is in the edit at the bottom. But in all honesty it is really just something I am writing to get practice in writing design patterns

Comment: @200_success Hello, I removed the method. That is going to be a method that I use to store info to the database but I just haven't writing it out yet

Comment: Have you tested whether your code works or is it all hypothetical?

Comment: @Mast Yes I have tested it against using the stored sample variables and have just tested it again against a real database using dynamic input acquired from a form I built. So it works in both scenarios. :-)